# Regex. PCRE. Find repeated words anywhere in the text

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to find words which are repeated **3 or more** times **anywhere** in the text.
It's quite easy to find consecutive repeated words like this:

```
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b
```

But i really can't get an idea how to set one backreference for each of this words. I should only set one backreference for each group of repeated words.

How to select **more** and **more** of **words** and **words** **words** and even **more** of those **more**

Is this possible to backreference **more** and **words** in this example?

```
\b(\w+).*\1\b
```

Comment: If you want to match at least 3 times the same word, perhaps using a positive lookahead a and 3 capturing groups `\b(\w{4,})\b(?=.*?(\1).*?(\1))`  https://regex101.com/r/XfkNTd/1

Comment: Bro, it's awesome, exactly what i need, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I have added it an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments, for your requirement you could use:

```
\b(\w{4,})\b(?=.*?\b(\1)\b.*?\b(\1)\b)
```

**About the groups**

The pattern makes use of a capturing group outside and 2 capturing groups inside the positive lookahead.

For every word captured in group 1, the nearest 2 words are captured in group 2 and 3 making them at least 3 times repeated.

The thing to remember is that there are overlapping matches if processing the groups and matches afterwards.

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w{4,}` Match 4 or more times a word character
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
  - `\b(\1)\b` Capture **group 2**, match group 1
  - `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
  - `\b(\1)\b` Capture **group 3** match group 1
- `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XfkNTd/1)

**Edit**

To match a word followed by 2 times but not 3 times the same word, you could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert group 1 is followed by 2 times group 1 and a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert that group 1 is not followed 3 times by group 1.

```
\b(\w{4,})(?=(?:.*\b\1\b){2})(?!(?:.*\b\1\b){3})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MBdlKi/1)

Comment: Can you do the same but without setting more than 1 backreference? Don't necessarily need to match the first occurrence of the word. Can you avoid a match in >word< word word word, and match word >word< word word? Match if it's followed by 2 occurences, don't match if it's followed by 3)

Comment: Basically this is correct - https://regex101.com/r/XfkNTd/3 - but the problem is that it still matches more than one repeated word. So when there are only 3 words - it matches only first one, and it's cool, but when there are 4 words - it matches first 2 occurrences, which is wrong. It should match only one occurrence even when there are 10+ repeated words

Comment: @AlexSmoke Perhaps like this? Assert that there are 2, but not 3. https://regex101.com/r/MBdlKi/1

Comment: YES YES an YES. Exactly. Many thanks. Could you please update your answer, so i will accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern should work:

```
\b(\w+)\b(.*?\b\1\b){2}
```

### Demo

This matches any word, followed by the same occurrence two more times, anywhere in the text.

**Edit:**

If, for some reason, you want use two different backreferences here, then try the following pattern:

```
\b(\w+)\b.*?(\1).*?\2
```

The definition of the second backreference is trivial, and is just `(\1)`, i.e. the captured first backreference, which of course is also just the same repeated word.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear enogh, i need to backreference EACH word that repeated 3 or more times

Comment: @user1274184 But what is the point of that requirement if we are trying to match the _same_ word three times?  Isn't the first backreference identical to any ones which might follow?

Comment: I need to set one backreference for each group of repeated words.

Comment: _Why_ do you think you need to do this?

Comment: No reason man, just learning regexes and having problem to solve this task. It's just a regex puzzle,.

Comment: @AlexSmoke I updated my answer with something which might be along the lines of what you're looking for.  Note that I probably would _not_ do it this way, however.

Comment: I updated my question, please look at it again. The thing is that i need to only set one backreference for each group of repeated words.

Comment: Now I am confused.  My original regex already is setting only one backreference.

Comment: Your first solution is great, when it's like that - https://regex101.com/r/XfkNTd/3 - but the problem is that it still matches more than one repeated word. So when there are only 3 words - it matches only first one, and it's cool, but when there are 4 words - it matches first 2 occurencies, which is wrong. It should match only one occurence even when there are 10+ repeated words

Comment: Depending on the regex tool you are using, this might even be a moot point.  What tool are you using?

Comment: Currently just the engine built in regex101. The regex itself matches all occurences that followed before 2 another occurences, so when there will be 5 repeated words - it will match first 3, and i need to match only one, not necessarily the first one, could be even last